# How to restore network-manager?

Tags: indicator, network-manager

I've broken network-manager trying to compile it from source, the applet no longer shows in the panel and I can't connect to any of my (wireless) networks. How might I restore it? I've tried reinstalling the network-manager packages from main repository but had no luck recreating the applet icon/indicator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem. A short-cut to get it working again is to just use Wicd - http://www.wicd.net/ - which is an alternative to network manager.

The other way is to restore network manager from the repository again. Run `sudo make uninstall` and delete any network manager libraries, `apt-get --purge remove network-manager` (and any other packages), and re-install all the packages, and gnome-networkmanager.

Also, running nm-applet from within the terminal might generate some more useful debugging information - primarily identifying whether the applet could create a d-bus connection to the network manager.